# how to display binary tree level wise from mysql using php?

Tags: php, mysql, binary-tree

QS: I have written a code using php mysql to display tree level wise using recursion. But the tree is not displaying properly. Only the first node is displayed and other node come as 0 (empty). I have checked and found **level** value is not changed . It always remain 1. Kindly give me suggestion so that i can print the same in tree structure level wise.

```
for($i=1;$i<=$height;$i++)
{
displayTree($memberID,$i);
echo "\n";
}
....
....
function displayTree($memId,$level)
{ 
    if($memId=="0")
        return;
    else if($level==1)
        echo "<br>".$level." ".$memId;
    elseif($level>1)
    {

        $leftChld=GetLeft($memId);
        displayTree($leftChld,($level-1));
        $rightChld=GetRight($memId);
        displayTree($rightChld,$level-1);

    }
}
```